# Spring aggregated jar

Tags: java, spring

Is there a jar file somewhere that aggregates all the small jars in Spring 3.0.6 distribution, like the one that I know exists for Jetty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like the old spring-full.jar(<2.0) and spring.jar(<3.0)? One jar with everything.

I think they stopped it as spring eco system is so large now, so if they included everything it would be huge. And most of it not needed.

Don't know a ready made solution nor a non maven solution.

You could however roll your own maven pom project that only depends on the core jars you need. Still multiple jars though as in a normal parent pom dependecy.

Or create a maven assembly that assembles all the jars content into one.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of the Spring modules can be found here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-modules

You should only include the modules for the functionalities that you need.

Also note, searching for jars is easy on http://www.jarvana.com

There used to be something as spring-full but not for version 3.0.6:
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=project&project=spring+full

You can also search in the maven repo:
http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=spring

I hope this helps you a little bit.